# How can I pass data to the Excel Sheet and process the data then resulted output need to retrive using Java?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet application. I have to pass parameters to sheet then Excel sheet evaluates the date and Need to read the resulted data through using JAVA. Is there any API to achieve this ? Please help me by suggesting correct way to complete it. 
Thank you

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+java+api

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at
http://poi.apache.org/

This project has API's for accessing MS Office file formats from Java.

The specific part for Excel is found here:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Bye,
Markus

Comment: Yup, poi is the only free good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Java Excel API](http://www.easyxls.com/java-excel-library). You can pass your dates to sheet and evaluate the formulas.

```
// Create a sheet
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument(); 
ExcelWorksheet xlsWorksheet = new ExcelWorksheet("Sheet1"); 
xls.easy_addWorksheet(xlsWorksheet); 

// Pass params to the sheet 
ExcelTable xlsTable = xlsWorksheet.easy_getExcelTable(); 
xlsTable.easy_getCell(0,0).setValue("1"); 
xlsTable.easy_getCell(1,0).setValue("2"); 
xlsTable.easy_getCell(2,0).setValue("3"); 

// Add your formula 
xlsTable.easy_getCell(3,0).setValue("=SUM(A1:A3)"); 

// Evaluate the formulas 
xlsWorksheet.easy_computeFormulas(xls, true); 

// Get the formula result
String result = xlsTable.easy_getCell(3,0).getFormulaResultValue());
```